# Is AOP the correct approach?

Tags: spring, aop

I know people generally use AOP for logging and things of that nature. Currently I have a functionality that requires MOST pieces of that application page.

I had a couple questions.

1) Would using Spring AOP be the proper way to address this issue. Or is there something else. Javascript on the front end has to access the cookie.

2) Is the concept of an aspect similar to what an interceptor is. That's the impression I get but wanted to clarify

EDIT - I have an application which basically retrieves some information and sets a cookie based on location of IP. Many pages within this web application will need this information - zip code for example on the page. These cookies need to be used by javascript. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Can you expand a lot?  I'm really not sure what you're asking.  It would probably help to explain what the functionality is, and to replace words like "that" or "this issue" with explanations of what you meant.

Comment: Not clear for what logic you are consider to use AOP - you will neeed to elaborate. Yes aspect similar to interceptor / filter. Typically you use interceptor / filter for web layer where you need access to request / response and use aspects for the application layer.

Comment: But yes, you can think of an interceptor as being a type of aspect.

Comment: Why not just put it in session? There are a variety of ways to get at it via JS. But how the info gets into session (or a cookie) is something an interceptor/etc could be used for, sure.

Answer (score 0):

What application page?  I don't understand the first sentence.  AOP is a server-side technology, so I don't see where JavaScript and cookies come in.

It's hard to decide whether simple HTTP filters or Spring AOP is the way to go without more details.

Interceptors and HTTP filters are similar in spirit to before-advice in AOP.  AOP includes after and error advice as well, so I think it's a more inclusive idea.

I'd be worried about an app that had every part using the functionality of a given page without knowing more.

Comment: I wouldn't characterise it as server-side; you can use Spring for clients too. AOP is a basic technology for wrapping code around (and, in general, also injecting it into) methods.

Comment: Of course you can use Spring for clients; I wouldn't use AOP on a JSP.

Comment: @DonalFellows I think you meant you can use AOP for clients too?

Comment: @duffymo But you could use AOP in JavaScript (or something that ends up as JS)... And "using AOP on a JSP" could mean several things, including wrapping JSP fragments in (something), like SiteMesh can do.

Comment: Nope, I've never done either with AOP.  I don't think I'd ever want to .

Comment: My point was that you can use AOP anywhere you can use Java objects, but I merrily admit that mixing it with JSP makes my head hurt (especially when thinking about deploying!)

Comment: So why recommend such a thing?  Makes no sense to me.

Comment: @duffymo First of all, that was me, and second of all, I didn't *recommend* it, just said it's possible. AOP has myriad uses, including in JS, including wrapping content (really, that's all something like Tiles or SiteMesh does). There's nothing headache-inducing about it at all, it's just another tool.